# Translating label for references collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, foreign-keys

i have form with one selectbox ([collection_select](https://github.com/roolo/mwstt/blob/master/app/views/datetimes/_form.html.erb#L16)) for references column. What is proper way to translate label for this widget? For all others a use default Model.human_attribute_name ([my code](https://github.com/roolo/mwstt/blob/master/config/locales/en.yml#L12), [Translations for Active Record Models](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models))

Comment: The links lead to 404 on github so there is not enough information in the question to provide an answer (IMO).

Comment: I am sorry. I've deleted linked branch and forgot for links in this post. Now it should be better ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use in your `[language].yml` file:

```
attributes:
  my_model:
    property: 'translatet property label'
    [...]
```

You can simply use the following in your view:

```
<%= form_for([...]) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :property %><br />
    <%= f.collection_select [...] %>
  </div>
  [...]
```

Comment: I completely forgot this question. I find it out few weeks ago http://bit.ly/izAjRu , but thanks